# SVG curved path as mask

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape, curves

I'm trying to use a curved path as a mask (Top right corner should be round). The svg is correctly rendered in current browsers but when I convert the svg to PDF or an image the curve gets lost. I have tried Inkscape, ImageMagick and rsvg-convert. Is there something wrong with my svg? Or is there any other way to create a mask with one rounded corner?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="240mm" height="330mm">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mymask">
      <path d="M0 0 L762.52754 0 Q779.52754 0 779.52754 17 L779.52754 1098.42517 Q779.52754 1098.42517 779.52754 1098.42517 L0 1098.42517 Q0 1098.42517 0 1098.42517 L0 0 Q0 0 0 0 Z" fill="white" id="path" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <svg version="1.1" width="220mm" height="310mm" x="10mm" y="10mm">
    <svg width="212mm" height="298mm" x="4mm" y="5mm">
      <g mask="url(#mymask)">
        <title>Layer 1</title>
        <g id="svg_1">
          <rect width="220mm" height="310mm" fill="red" id="svg_2" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: I just ran it through an online converter(http://www.fileformat.info/convert/image/svg2pdf.htm) and it worked, so your svg is solid, and something is happening in the conversion.

Comment: have you tried http://cairosvg.org/?

Comment: Hi miah, thanks for your reply. Yes I have tested cairo too. Did not work. Yes, I think the SVG is correct. When I copy the same path outside of the mask it will work like expected. So there must be some kind of issue when inside a mask.